# React: Running function in child component runs function in all child components of same kind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I have an issue where when a function runs in one child component, all the children of the same type will seemingly run the same function as well. Here is what the code looks like:

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
...
constructor(){
    this.state = { items:[...] }
}
render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Child id="child1id"... items={this.state.items}/>
        <Child id="child2id"... items={this.state.items}/>
      </div>  
    );
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
...
constructor(){
     this.state = { ..., items: this.props.items, ... };
     this.id = this.props.id;
}
orderArray(){...}
needsToScroll(){...}
setArray(){
   this.setState(state => ({ items: this.orderArray(this.state.items) }));
}
incrementArray(){
    this.setArray();
    $('.' + this.id + '.row').css("bottom", "0px");
    if(this.needsToScroll()){
        $('.' + this.id + '.row').animate({
            bottom: $('.' + this.id + '.row').outerHeight().toString() +"px"
        },
        1000, "linear");
        $('.' + this.id + '.row').promise().done(this.incrementArray.bind(this));
    }
    else{
        var new_array = this.state.items;
        new_array.map((item, index) => {
            new_array[index].index = index + 1;
        });
        this.setState(state => ({items: new_array}));
    }
}
componentDidMount(){
    if(this.needsToScroll()){
        this.incrementArray();
    }
    else{
        var new_array = this.state.items;
        new_array.map((item, index) => {
            new_array[index].index = index + 1;
        });
        this.setState(state => ({items: new_array}));
    }
}
...
render(){
    return (
        <div className="child">
        {this.rowTitle(this.state.rowTitles)}
            {this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
                <div key={this.id+index} className={this.isDivider(item)} style={this.rowStyle(item)} ref={this.rowRef}>
                    <div key={this.id + index.toString() + "1"} style={this.textStyle(item)}>{item.title}</div>
                    <div key={this.id + this.id + index.toString() + "2"} style={this.textStyle(item)}>{item.date}</div>
                    <div key={this.id + index.toString() + "3"} style={this.textStyle(item)}>{item.area}</div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
}

const WrapperComponent = ReactDOM.render(<Wrapper/>, document.getElementById("wrapper"));
```

What happens is `setArray` gets called twice by both components in 1 second increments when they are supposed to only call that function once to modify their own state in 1 second increments. I assume it's because `incrementArray` gets called twice from the two different components resulting in this behavior.

I made sure that the jQuery selectors were getting the right components via `console.log` and they were doing so. Therefore, it's the only conclusion I could come to. If this is correct, how can I make sure that each component is only calling the function once for the state of each individual component?

I cut out some of the methods from the code. If necessary, I can add them back in. The code is a representation of what it is.

EDIT: Clarified the problem

EDIT2: Added back necessary code

EDIT3: Added clarifying ... for constructor of child

EDIT4: Added code to have the answer make sense.

Comment: Ok, there's a bunch of stuff that is going wrong here. 
1. Don't mix jquery and React. - React has its own sense of the DOM and if you interfere with it, the results are going to be unpredictable. 
2. You are accessing `this.id` directly - are you meaning to access this.props.id?

Comment: My apologies, that is one line of code I shouldn't have removed. It's a variable I declared in the constructor of Child in order to get the id of the component.

Comment: I use jquery for doing the animations for the rows. Would there be a way to do that using React instead?

Comment: You could write your animations with plain CSS - or take a look at this: https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html

Comment: I originally did the animations with plain CSS, but I needed to be able to modify the values for the animations so I switched to using jquery. edit: however, the one thing I'm still confused about is why when the children components call the function `setArray` that is a part of the component the function is seemingly called for both children instead of just the one that called it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some work on the problem, I found a solution that fixed the issue. The solution was to create two separate arrays for each child element and bring those into each child via props.

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { children: [{ name: "child1", items:[...]},                          
                                  { name: "child2", items:[...]}]};
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div class="wrapper">
            {this.state.children.map((item) => (
                <Child id={item.name} ... items={item.items} />
            ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The child code remained pretty much the same. In other words, it wasn't an issue with a function being called multiple times, rather each child was modifying the same array. I will be adding code to the question to clarify the point better (I should have added more information, so my bad).